# Zurb Foundation Custom Javascript

Tags: zurb-foundation

I assume that as app.css is for your own custom CSS rules, then app.js is for your own custom scripts?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct yes, though it's usually for calling other scripts you have included though rather than writing full length scripts.

Sample App.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*
    *  FAAAAANCY BOX!
    */

    $('.fancybox').fancybox();


    //Creates the datatable JS on the demo tables.aspx page
    oTable = $('#data-table').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"datatable-header"fl>t<"datatable-footer"ip>',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "<span>Show entries:</span> _MENU_"
        }
    });

});
```

So else where you may have included the datatables plugin and the fancybox plugin, in the app.js you will call the functions you may want to include across the entire site.

Though you can rename it or use inline JS on the pages if you so wish.

Comment: There is mention in the documentation stating precisely this, in the [Clearing issues with IE8](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php) section.